# Pasar variables por php

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo .php el cual se encarga de gestionar noticias de una web, necesito filtrar por categorías si el usuario presiona determinada opción en el menú. Estoy enviado variables por medio de php al mismo archivo para posteriormente recibir el valor de la variable y plasmarlo en mi consulta SQL.

El problema es que al entrar por primera vez a la pagina me da un error, ya que estoy tratando de recuperar el valor de una variable que aun no existe.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto?

Así hago el envió de mis variables:

```
<li><a href="noticias.php">Todas</a> </li>
<li><a href="noticias.php?categoria=academicas">Academicas</a></li>
<li><a href="noticias.php?categoria=deportivas">Deportivas</a></li>
<li><a href="noticias.php?categoria=otras">Otras</a></li>
```

Y de esta manera las recibo en el mismo archivo **noticias.php**:

```
<?php
$consulta_tabla=($_GET['categoria']);

if($consulta_tabla == "deportivas"){
    $categoria = "deportivas";
}else
    if($consulta_tabla == "academicas"){
    $categoria = "academicas";
}else
        if($consulta_tabla == "otras"){
    $categoria = "otras";
}
?>
```

Aquí esta el problema, ya que cuando se carga por primera vez **noticia.php** $consulta_tabla no tiene ningún valor.

Answer (score 8):

Puedes establecer una consulta por defecto:

```
$consulta_tabla = "otras";
$consulta_tabla=($_GET['categoria']);
```

o hacer una condicional que obtendría el mismo resultado:

```
if(isset($_GET['categoria']) && $_GET['categoria] != null){
    $consulta_tabla = $_GET['categoria'];
}else{
    $consulta_tabla = 'otras';
}
```

o lo más recomendable hacer comprobaciones a través de un switch:

```
switch($_GET['categoria']){
    case 'deportivas':
        $categoria = "deportivas";
    break;

    case 'academicas':
        $categoria = "academicas";
    break;

    case 'otras':
        $categoria = "otras";
    break;

    default:
        $categoria = "otras";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Para comprobar si una variable tiene algún valor asignado puedes usar **isset()**.
Te sugiero que en vez de anidar tantos if utilices un switch.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$consulta_tabla=($_GET['categoria']);
if(isset($consulta_tabla)){
  switch ($consulta_tabla) {
    case 'deportivas':
      $categoria = "deportivas";
      break;
    case 'academicas':
      $categoria = "academicas";
      break;
    case 'otras':
      $categoria = "otras";
      break;
    default:
      # code...
      break;
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas 1 sola variable para una comparacion es mejor que uses el `switch/case` con esto podrás tener mayor orden, el `if` es para múltiples validaciones dentro de una etc....
respondiendo a tu pregunta

```
if( !isset($_GET["categoria"]) ){
    $categoria = '';
}

// validacion a la DB
if( !$categoria ){
    // no agregar el SQL que contiene el campo de 'categoria'
    $sql_cate = '';
}else{
    $sql_cate = " and categoria = '$categoria' ";
}
```